# Problemas en juego tipo snake python

Tags: python

El código deja de funcionar en la línea 25 por el siguiente error y ya he intentado muchas cosas, lo siento si es muy básico.

> `if map_objects[POS_X] == cordinate_x and map_objects[POS_Y] == cordinate_y:` TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
import readchar
import os

POS_X = 0
POS_Y = 1

MAP_WIDTH = 20
MAP_HEIGHT = 15

player_pos = [12, 5]

map_objects = [[2, 8], [9, 11], [2, 6], [5, 7]]

while True:
    print("+" + "-" * MAP_WIDTH * 3 + "+")

    for cordinate_y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        print("|", end="")

        for cordinate_x in range(MAP_WIDTH):

            char_to_draw = " "

            for map_objects in map_objects:
                if map_objects[POS_X] == cordinate_x and map_objects[POS_Y] == cordinate_y:
                    char_to_draw = "+"

            if player_pos[POS_X] == cordinate_x and player_pos[POS_Y] == cordinate_y:
                char_to_draw = "@"

            print("{}".format(char_to_draw), end="")
        print("|")

    print("+" + "-" * MAP_WIDTH * 3 + "+")

    print("[W] Up [S] Down [A] Left [D] Right")

    # Ask to user where he want to move

    # player_move_ask = (input("Where do you want to move? [W]Up [S]Down [A]Left [D]Right"))
    # if player_move_ask == "W":
    direction = readchar.readchar().decode()

    if direction == "w":
        player_pos[POS_Y] -= 1
        player_pos[POS_Y] %= MAP_HEIGHT
    elif direction == "s":
        player_pos[POS_Y] += 1
        player_pos[POS_Y] %= MAP_HEIGHT
    elif direction == "a":
        player_pos[POS_X] -= 1
        player_pos[POS_X] %= MAP_WIDTH
    elif direction == "d":
        player_pos[POS_X] += 1
        player_pos[POS_X] %= MAP_WIDTH
    elif direction == "q":
        break

    os.system("cls")
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está aqui:

```
for map_objects in map_objects:
```

estas ocupando el mismo nombre para la lista y para la variable de control del `for`.

Solución: inventa otro nombre para la variable. Por ejemplo:

```
for mapobj in map_objects:
```

Obvio, tienes que cambiarlo en el resto del código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en esto  y llevaba un rato rompiéndome la cabeza.